# Как работает метод pop()

Tags: python, методы

Объясните, пожалуйста. Почему метод .pop() в цикле for извлекает из списка именно 6 элементов?

```
phrase = "Don't panic!"
plist = list(phrase)
print(phrase)
print(plist)
for nplist in plist:
        plist.pop(4)
new_phrase = "".join(plist)
print(plist)
print(new_phrase)
```

Comment: Это на конкретной реализации/версии питона он извлекает 6 элементов. А на другой может все быть по другому. Если вы модифицируете список по которому итерируете, то результат непредсказуемый. В данном случае, очевидно, итератор внутри хранит индекс элемента, а операция pop уменьшает размер списка. Получается за одну итерацию продвигаемся на один элемент за счет цикла и уменьшаем длину списка на 1. Изначально в списке 12 элементов, несложно посчитать, что будет 6 итераций.

Comment: Воспользутесь дебаггером https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger